# Is there a reason not to use white spaces for column names?

Tags: mysql

Why should I use this:

```
alter table `user` add column `first_name`;
```

Instead of this:

```
alter table `user` add column `first name`;
```

Comment: Because you can skip using the awful backticks?

Comment: And because when you have white space in entity names, there is a trickle-down effect where all code that references that table must have special handling for those column names. What do you GAIN by having a space instead of _? Does not having to press the shift key for that keystroke improve your productivity?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not stating that one is better over the other. I guess you answered the question, if there's no other convention or things that could possibly cause errors.

Comment: @ypercube I like to be consistent in case I ever use a table called 'table' or something.

Comment: Internally, column names are just strings.  Table names and database names, however, show up in the OS in file names and directory names -- this could lead to some 'tricke-down' effects.

Comment: Because spaces are the devils handy work.

Comment: Just because you can throw yourself off a cliff into stormy shark-infested waters, doesn't mean that you should!

Comment: @Vérace Just because it's save to do what everyone has been doing, doesn't mean it's bad to think outside the box.

Comment: Putting spaces in field/table/file names is just storing up difficulties for yourself - my point was that even if your RDBMS (in this case MySQL) supports it, is **NOT** a good reason for doing it. Your app will be non-portable and furthermore, typos and SQL errors will be difficult to spot and/or debug.